# How to assign the result returned by the bash command to the arg parameter or the param parameter?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use `rtabmap_ros`, I need to specify the database save path.The feasible method is to use the following method to assign values in rtabmap node:

> param name = "database_path" type = "string" value = "~ / .ros / rtabmap.db"

But I want to add the current time to the generated database file name.For example, when I execute `date + '~ / rtabmap_databases / rtabmap_% Y-% m-% d-% Ih-% Mm-% Ss.db'` in bash, the screen prints `~ / rtabmap_databases / rtabmap_2020-01-10 -10h-02m-04s.db`. I want to pass this string to the `database_path` parameter of `rtabmap` node. Therefore, I use the following methods for parameter assignment:

> param name="database_path"        command="date +'~/rtabmap_databases/rtabmap_%Y-%m-%d-%Ih-%Mm-%Ss.db'"

but the following error occurs:

> [FATAL] (2020-01-10 10:12:27.004) Rtabmap.cpp:298::init() Condition (UFile::getExtension(_databasePath).compare("db") == 0) not met!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341402/how-to-assign-the-result-returned-by-the-bash-command-to-the-arg-parameter-or-the-param-parameter?/) by [willzoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/50793/willzoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem is that the resulting string from the command `date + '~ / rtabmap_databases / rtabmap_% Y-% m-% d-% Ih-% Mm-% Ss.db'` has a trailing newline character, thus the check on the last characters of the string (representing the file extension) fails.

Try to replace the command with the following:

```
<param name="database_path" command="bash -c &quot;date +'~/rtabmap_databases/rtabmap_%Y-%m-%d-%Ih-%Mm-%Ss.db' | tr -d '\n'&quot;"/>
```

It worked fine on my laptop using ROS melodic.

---

Originally posted by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) with karma: 114 on 2020-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1